# align part of text left and part right in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, alignment

I am filling a UITableView table with nutrition facts. Each row includes the absolute amount of the nutrient as well as the percent daily value. I would like to align the amount to the left side of each row and the percent daily value to the right side so that the information looks neater and so that all of the values line up. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NutritionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"NutritionCell"];
    }


    CGRect oldFrame = cell.frame;
    cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width/2, oldFrame.size.height);
    cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x + tableView.frame.size.width/2, oldFrame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width/2, oldFrame.size.height);

    cell.textLabel.text = [factamount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [percentDV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Left";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Right";

    return cell;
}
```

If you want to use multiple custom labels in cells(more than two), you can do that as well and add it as subview of `cell.contentView` and align using `textAlignment` property. You can set the frame for these labels to display in appropriate places.

In that case you need to do it as

```
myLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
myLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: @maximum411, In order to set frame, you can try `"cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(..."`. Do the same for other label also.

Comment: Hmm... that did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @maximum411, How are you setting frame? And what is the frame you have set? Did you try reducing the width of left side label and check? If not, you can create a new label and add on the cell. But this one should definitely work. If possible, post a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with UITableViewCellStyleValue1. Which automatically adds 2 labels to the cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellID = @"CELLID";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"AMOUNT TEXT";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"PERCENT TEXT";
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I used this code, but now I am only seeing the content for cell.textlabel.text

Comment: This is the code I am using now- should this be working (included above in edited question)?

Comment: Is it something to do with your frame setting code? You shouldn't need to do that - as UITableViewCell will automatically align one to the left and one to the right - try commenting that out and see if it works :) I tested my code on a new project and it worked how it should.